# How do I auto populate row data based on criteria but have return values editable?

Tags: indexing, match, vlookup

Hello I'm brand new to the script world!

Problem: Vlookup return is not editable.
I tried IndexMatch without success.

I am making a truck maintenance file. The trucks have hour and kilometer trackers that are updated hourly in sheets. Our goal is to enter truck unit number and have the date, hours, and kilometers populate our mechanics notes. From Data entry sheet a button will enter that data into each units maintenance page. Vlookup returned the right results but if an adjustment on date, hours, or kilometers needs to be made the cell can't be edited.

I am looking for a hand in setting this up.

I will share the sheet.

Search Key 'Data Entry A2'

Range       'Data Entry A8:C17'

Index      'Data Entry A8:A17'

Thanks[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E36Qi3PqtX9wyuRLLf393qsoy_mneBLUurS4DE7BjAs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok Thanks I'll do that next time. I will delete this post I got it figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Menu");
 var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
 var col = activeCell.getColumn();
 var row = 2;
 if (col == 1 ) { // update when change in column 1, adapt if neededfunction 
CopyRow() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var menuSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Menu");
  var inventorySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");

  menuSheet.getRange("C2:D2").clear();

  var partNumber = menuSheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();

  var lastRow = inventorySheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var foundRecord = false;

 for(var j = 2; j <  lastRow; j++)
 {
    if(inventorySheet.getRange(j,1).getValue() ==partNumber)
    {
      var nextRow = menuSheet.getRange(2,3);
      var getCopyRange = inventorySheet.getRange('B' + j + ':C' + j);
      getCopyRange.copyTo(menuSheet.getRange(2, 3));
      foundRecord = true; 
    }
}

  if(foundRecord == false)
  {
    menuSheet.getRange(5,1).setValue(['(NO RECORDS FOUND)']); 
  }
 }
}
```